# Finding and Filtering a particular text in a concrete column

Tags: vba, excel

hopefully someone will have a good idea how to solve my problem that I got stuck with.
I have a column named "Contents Total"

I set up two autofilters in different columns, and then, in this column "Contents Total", I want to find all rows, which contain the word "Rebill".

Setup of the filters works good but the part of the code, where I am trying to find the word "Rebill", is not working at all.

This is my code:

```
Sheets("DATA").Select

Const TagetColumnLabel_2 = "Logistics/CTD"
Const TagetColumnLabel_1 = "Contents Total"
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim r4, r00, r5, z As Long

Dim myArray As String
Group = Array("SG185", "US1038", "AU1063", "FK1043")
Dim element As Variant

SubGroup = Array("Investigational Drugs", "IP Return")
Dim SubElement As Variant

SubGroup1 = Array("Kitproduction")
Dim SubElement1 As Variant


Set tbl = Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("tb_DATA")

r4 = Rows("1").Find("Ch To key").Column
r00 = Rows("1").Find("Logistics/CTD").Column
r5 = Rows("1").Find("Contents Total").Column

    For Each element In Group

        If element = "SG185" Then

                With Sheets("DATA")
                    .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r4, Criteria1:=element
                    .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r00, Criteria1:=""

                For i = 1 To tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

                    If InStr(1, tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Column, "Rebill") Then
                        tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Service/Log Formula]]"

                    Else

                        For Each SubElement In SubGroup
                                .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r5, Criteria1:=SubElement
                                tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Service/Log Formula]]"
                        Next SubElement

                        For Each SubElement1 In SubGroup1
                                .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r5, Criteria1:=SubElement1
                                tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Search]]"
                        Next SubElement1
                    End If
                Next i
            End With

            tbl.ShowAutoFilter = False
        Else

                With Sheets("DATA")
                .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r4, Criteria1:=element
                .ListObjects("tb_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=r00, Criteria1:=""
                    tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Service/Log Formula]]"
            End With
        End If
    Next element

tbl.ShowAutoFilter = False
```

This part of the code is not working:

```
For i = 1 To tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

If InStr(1, tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Column, "Rebill") Then
tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Service/Log Formula]]"
```

Please, does someone know how to easily look for the particular text/word "Rebill"?
I appreciate very much every advise. 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your code running with "on error resume next" in it somewhere higher up? I can't get it to run without lots of errors.

Comment: Can you convert this into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVE)](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  As it stands, that is an awful lot of code to [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok).  If you can make this question easier to follow you are more likely to receive a working answer.  Don't forget, your question is competing with all the others for the communities attention.

Comment: yes, the code is running without any error... it just does not consider the loop and the If InStr statement. I think this part of the code is completely wrong but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I know that the code is a bit complicated, and not so nice. The main question is how can I search for a cells in the column named "Contents Total", which contain a word (in this case "Rebill"), and then how to display/filter only these rows. I just need a hint, and then I will make adjustments to fit it into my code. Just need the initial idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the fact that you are attempting to use InStr in what in essence returns a column number, try changing your problem code with something like;

```
          For i = 1 To tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                Dim val As Variant
                Dim foundrebil As Range
                val = tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_1).DataBodyRange.Column 'find column number and store in val
                Set foundrebill = Sheets("DATA").Columns(val).Find(What:="ReBill") 'search for Rebill in that column
                If Not foundrebill Is Nothing Then 'if found
                    val2 = tbl.ListColumns(TagetColumnLabel_2).DataBodyRange.Column 'get the column number of TargetColumnLabel_2
                    Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, val2).FormulaR1C1 = "=tb_DATA[[#This Row],[Service/Log Formula]]" 'enter formula in that column and row
                Else
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the code is a bit complicated, and not so nice.

I had some trouble understanding exactly what you want, but I picked up that you're filtering for Rebill in Contents Total and you've got two other filter conditions on the table.

At the end of the code `rVisible` will hold a reference to the Rebill data, or `rSelection` for the first 10 rows of Rebill data.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rContentsTot As Range
    Dim rChToKey As Range
    Dim rCTD As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lTblFirstCol As Long
    Dim rVisible As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rSelection As Range
    Dim lCounter As Long

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set tbl = wrkSht.ListObjects("tb_DATA")

    With tbl

        lTblFirstCol = .HeaderRowRange.Column

        Set rContentsTot = .HeaderRowRange.Find("Contents Total")
        Set rChToKey = .HeaderRowRange.Find("Ch To key")
        Set rCTD = .HeaderRowRange.Find("Logistics/CTD")

        'Only continue if all columns have been found.
        If Not rContentsTot Is Nothing And Not rChToKey Is Nothing And Not rCTD Is Nothing Then

            'Turn on table autofilter if it's not on, or show all data if it is.
            If .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
                .Range.AutoFilter
            Else
                .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If

            'Filter as required.  Field:=1 is first column in table, Field:=5 is the fifth.
            'NB - Is there a better way to return the correct column within the table?
            '     This works, but feel I should be able to equate the found column number to
            '     a column number within the table.
            With .Range
                .AutoFilter Field:=rCTD.Column - lTblFirstCol + 1, Criteria1:="3"
                .AutoFilter Field:=rChToKey.Column - lTblFirstCol + 1, Criteria1:="6"
                .AutoFilter Field:=rContentsTot.Column - lTblFirstCol + 1, Criteria1:="Rebill"
            End With

            '********************************
            'Not sure why I added this next bit of code - it gets the first 10 rows
            'of filtered data.  Think I must've combined two posts into one in my
            'mind overnight (started answering this question yesterday).
            'Anyway.... it's there, it does stuff, so I'm leaving it in
            '********************************

            'Now to grab the top 10 visible rows in the table.
            Set rVisible = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            For Each rRow In rVisible.Rows
                If lCounter < 10 Then
                    If lCounter = 0 Then
                        Set rSelection = rRow
                    Else
                        Set rSelection = Application.Union(rSelection, rRow)
                    End If
                    lCounter = lCounter + 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rRow

            'Remove filter and select the top 10 rows that appeared in the filter.
            .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            rSelection.Select

            '******************
            'End of extra code that you may or may not need
            '******************

        Else
            'Raise error as not all columns have been found.
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```